# Getting "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to" connecting hub with node

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

**OS:** Linux
**Selenium Version:**3.12
**Browser:** Chrome V66, 
**chromedriver** 2.38

Following is my Grid configuration:
Hub(Linux) runs on Jenkins machine(https://jenkins.us.abc.edu) with Selenium Grid Jenkins plugin.

Now i am trying to register my Node with json like below and starting Node:
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-rver-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig node.json

node.json

```
{
  "capabilities":
  [
    {
      "browserName": "firefox",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chrome",
      "maxInstances": 5,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    },
    {
      "browserName": "internet explorer",
      "maxInstances": 1,
      "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
    }
  ],
  "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
  "maxSession": 5,
  **"port": 17946,**
  "register": true,
  "registerCycle": 5000,
  **"hub": "http://jenkins.us.abc.edu:4444",**
  "nodeStatusCheckTimeout": 5000,
  "nodePolling": 5000,
  "role": "node",
  "unregisterIfStillDownAfter": 60000,
  "downPollingLimit": 2,
  "debug": false,
  "servlets" : [],
  "withoutServlets": [],
  "custom": {}
}
```

Following is Node console:

```
[uanem@usv-selapp-01 ~]$ java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-rver-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig node.json
09:37:49.054 INFO [GridLauncherV3.launch] - Selenium build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3'
09:37:49.059 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Launching a Selenium Grid node on port 17946
2018-05-28 09:37:49.175:INFO::main: Logging initialized @490ms to org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.log.StdErrLog
09:37:49.324 INFO [SeleniumServer.boot] - Selenium Server is up and running on port 17946
09:37:49.324 INFO [GridLauncherV3$3.launch] - Selenium Grid node is up and ready to register to the hub
09:37:49.332 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote$1.run] - Starting auto registration thread. Will try to register every 5000 ms.
09:37:49.332 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://jenkins.us.umuc.edu:4444/grid/register
09:37:50.866 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Updating the node configuration from the hub
09:37:50.965 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.hudson.plugins.selenium.JenkinsCapabilityMatcher could not be coerced to instance
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'usv-selapp-01.us.umuc.edu', ip: '10.190.33.90', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
09:37:50.965 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
09:39:11.333 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://jenkins.us.umuc.edu:4444/grid/register
09:39:11.392 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Updating the node configuration from the hub
09:39:11.404 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.hudson.plugins.selenium.JenkinsCapabilityMatcher could not be coerced to instance
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'usv-selapp-01.us.umuc.edu', ip: '10.190.33.90', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
09:39:11.405 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
09:40:31.602 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://jenkins.us.umuc.edu:4444/grid/register
09:40:31.632 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Updating the node configuration from the hub
09:40:31.642 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.hudson.plugins.selenium.JenkinsCapabilityMatcher could not be coerced to instance
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'usv-selapp-01.us.umuc.edu', ip: '10.190.33.90', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
09:40:31.642 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
09:41:51.809 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Registering the node to the hub: http://jenkins.us.umuc.edu:4444/grid/register
09:41:51.850 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - Updating the node configuration from the hub
09:41:51.856 WARN [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - error getting the parameters from the hub. The node may end up with wrong timeouts.hudson.plugins.selenium.JenkinsCapabilityMatcher could not be coerced to instance
Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
System info: host: 'usv-selapp-01.us.umuc.edu', ip: '10.190.33.90', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.10.0-862.el7.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_144'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
09:41:51.856 INFO [SelfRegisteringRemote.registerToHub] - The node is registered to the hub and ready to use
Here i could see the node is connected hub in my Jenkins Selenium Grid page at "10.190.33.90"
```

Following is my sample script:

```
@Test
    public void GoogleTest() throws Exception
    {

        System.out.println("I am in test");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();



        System.out.println("I am after setting chromedriver path ");

        **remoteWD = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://usv-bmsapp-01.us.abc.edu:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);**
        **//remoteWD = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("https://jenkins.us.abc.edu:4444/wd/hub"), capabilities);** 
        //remoteWD = new ChromeDriver(); 

        System.out.println("I am after RMD");

        remoteWD.get("http://www.google.com"); 
        WebElement element = remoteWD.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("Selenium WebDriver"); 
        element.submit();
        Thread.sleep(10000);
        System.out.println(remoteWD.getTitle());
        remoteWD.quit();

    }
```

Due to security reasons or whatever i am not able to connect "https://jenkins.us.abc.edu:4444/wd/hub", but when i give the server name like this "http://usv-bmsapp-01.us.abc.edu:4444/wd/hub" I am able to connect.

Following is the error message i am getting. Can someone help me where i am going wrong???

```
Running gridtest.GridTest
Configuring TestNG with: org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.conf.TestNG652Configurator@7dc5e7b4
I am before test
I am in test
I am after setting chromedriver path 
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 95.6 sec <<< FAILURE!
GoogleTest(gridtest.GridTest)  Time elapsed: 94.334 sec  <<< FAILURE!
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to 10.190.33.90:17946 [/10.190.33.90] failed: Connection timed out
Command duration or timeout: 92.06 seconds
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$24(ProtocolHandshake.java:359)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:362)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:136)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:586)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:217)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:140)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:153)
    at gridtest.GridTest.GoogleTest(GridTest.java:49)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Error forwarding the new session Error forwarding the request Connect to 10.190.33.90:17946 [/10.190.33.90] failed: Connection timed out
Build info: version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'
System info: host: 'usv-bmsapp-01.us.umuc.edu', ip: '10.190.32.186', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_77'
Driver info: driver.version: unknown
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.handler.RequestHandler.process(RequestHandler.java:117)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.process(DriverServlet.java:84)
    at org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.DriverServlet.doPost(DriverServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:841)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:535)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1595)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:188)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1253)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:168)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:473)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:166)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1155)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.Server.handle(Server.java:564)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:317)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:251)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:110)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable.invokePreferred(Invocable.java:128)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.Invocable$InvocableExecutor.invoke(Invocable.java:222)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:294)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:199)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:672)
    at org.seleniumhq.jetty9.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:590)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a couple of issues which you ned to address as follows:

### Selenium version

- Logs in *Node* depicts:

  - **Selenium** *version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'*
- Logs in *Console* depicts:

  - **Selenium** *version: '3.6.0', revision: '6fbf3ec767', time: '2017-09-27T15:28:36.4Z'*

### JDK version

- Logs in *Node* depicts:

  - **java.version** '1.8.0_144'
- Logs in *Console* depicts:

  - **java.version** '1.8.0_77'

### Node startup command

The command which you have used to register the node looks error-pront as follows:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-rver-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig node.json
```

It should have been:

```
java -jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver selenium-server-standalone-3.12.0.jar -role node -nodeConfig node.json
```

### Solution

- Upgrade *JDK* in *Selenium Grid Hub* and *Selenium Grid Node* to  recent levels [**JDK 8u171**](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Upgrade *Selenium Client* in *Selenium Grid Hub* and _Selenium Grid Node_to  current levels [**Version 3.12.0**](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [**ChromeDriver v2.38**](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at ***Chrome v66.x*** levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v2.38 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.38/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Use [*CCleaner*](https://www.ccleaner.com/ccleaner) tool to wipe off all the OS chores before and after the execution of your *test Suite*.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

### nodeConfig

To start simple you can reduce the **nodeConfig** i.e. **node.json** as follows:

```
{
    "capabilities": [
        {
            "browserName": "firefox",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "maxInstances": 5,
            "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        },
        {
        "browserName": "internet explorer",
        "maxInstances": 1,
        "seleniumProtocol": "WebDriver"
        }
    ],
        "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
        "maxSession": 5,
        "port": 5566,
        "host": ip,
        "register": true,
        "registerCycle": 5000,
        "hubPort": 4444,
        "hubHost": jenkins.us.abc.edu,
        "timeout":120,
        "browserTimeout":60
}
```

Comment: I dont have control on the Hub machine. However for Selenium Hub plugin in updated in Hub machine(Jenkins machine itself). For Node all of them are updated versions(Chrome, ChromeDriver etc...). Regarding Node.json, the above is the latest node.json format supported from Selenium 3 onwards. Is anything missing in node.json configuration?